# How to downgrade firebase-tools in cdm.exe to 6.0.0?

Tags: version, downgrade, firebase-tools

To choose the default project I had to use the arrow keys but they didn't work and at another stackoverflow forum they said I should downgrade the version of firebase-tools.

I've tried to uninstall firebase-tools and install the lower version by typing npm install firebase@6.0.0 but that doesn't work.